# Python's membership operator equivalent in PHP

Tags: php, python

Is there an equivalent in PHP of Python's Membership Operator?

Are the operators "in and not in" used in PHP universe?

Is there a straight way, as in Python, to rewrite this example in PHP?

```
ingredients = ['cheese', 'tomato', 'onion', 'pepperoni']
if 'oni' in ingredients:
   print("The letters 'oni' is available in the given ingredients")
else:
   print("The letters 'oni' is NOT available in the given ingredients")
```

or

```
if 'oni' in 'pepperoni':
    print("The letters 'oni' is available in the given ingredient")
else: 
    print ("The letters 'oni' is NOT available in the given ingredient")
```

I already know that there are millions of ways to get the same result in PHP, but the point is if the "membership operators" exists in PHP.

Comment: Yes it does, see https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_in_array.asp

Comment: of coarse ... http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php ... although why you would want to go from awesomeness to php i dont understand

Comment: Aderson give a look at https://www.w3schools.com/pHP/default.asp

@JoranBeasley maybe some client spec or company spec, i do love python but i worked so far with 5 different languages hahaha i do have to eat

Comment: PHP in_array function is similar but not the same of Python membership operator.

Comment: In my first example, PHP in_array is the solution, and in the second, PHP strpos() it is. That's it, in PHP there is necessary 2 functions to do the same of the Python membership operator.

Answer (score 2):

There you go! I hope this will helps.

```
<?php
$ingridients = array("Cheese", "Tomato", "Onion", "Pepperoni");

if (in_array("oni", $ingridients))
  {
  echo "The letters 'oni' is available in the given ingredients";
  }
 else
   {
   echo "The letters 'oni' is NOT available in the given ingredients";
  }
?>
```

Comment: Ok, now, try this in PHP

if 'oni' in 'pepperoni':
    print("The letters 'oni' is available in the given ingredients")
else: 
    print ("The letters 'oni' is NOT available in the given ingredients")

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your comment @Anderson . What do you mean to try this in PHP? The code is already PHP. Thanks.

Comment: Hi A Sanz. PHP in_array works for an array. But what I've given now, if 'oni' in 'pepperoni': print("The letters 'oni' is available in the given ingredient") else: print ("The letters 'oni' is NOT available in the given ingredient"), is just a string "pepperoni". While in Python it will result in The letters 'oni' is available in the given ingredient, in PHP will be NOT.

Answer (score 2):

No there is no single operator that does the same thing as the `in` operator in python.

PHP has a built-in function for just about everything though: as others have suggested, you can use `in_array` to check if an element exists in an array.

If you are trying to determine whether a string contains a substring (e.g. 'oni' in 'pepperoni') you can use PHP functions like `strpos`, `substr`, `preg_match`, etc.

Comment: You're the only one who understood and answered my question. You got the point of the question.

Answer (score 0):

As [jsaigle](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6189922/jsaigle) already [said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51069009/284325), there is no single operator that does the same thing as `in` and `not in` in Python.

Just for the fun of it, here's a wrapper to mimic it (see https://3v4l.org/ZfCBH):

```
<?php

if (Term::create('oni')->in(['cheese', 'tomato', 'onion', 'pepperoni'])) {
    echo '"oni" is available in the given ingredients'.PHP_EOL;
} else {
    echo '"oni" is NOT available in the given ingredients'.PHP_EOL;
}

if (Term::create('oni')->in('pepperoni')) {
    echo '"oni" is available in the given ingredient'.PHP_EOL;
} else {
    echo '"oni" is NOT available in the given ingredient'.PHP_EOL;
}

// Pretend the following isn't here

class Term
{
    public $value;

    public function __construct($value)
    {
        $this->value = $value;
    }

    public static function create($value)
    {
        return new self($value);
    }

    public function in($search)
    {
        return array_reduce((array) $search, function ($carry, $item) {
            return $carry ?: (bool) mb_substr_count($item, $this->value);
        });
    }

    public function notIn($search)
    {
        return !$this->in($array);
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Despite the most answers didn't understand what was written in the question but with one right answer, I can conclude

There is NOT a single operator nor function in PHP that does the same thing as the "in not in" membership operator in Python.